# iTunes Syncing Files information - Total MB, Speed of Transfer, etc

Tags: itunes, statistics

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to get more information on the syncing process - i.e. speed of the transfer, MB remaining, estimated time, etc.

I ask because I was syncing some iTunesU files which are pretty big - 3.2GB - over Wi-Fi, and thought it would be useful to know exactly how quickly they're being transfered, and how much I've got to go. All there is normally is a bar that slowly fills up. Surely there's a way to access this info, perhaps in a terminal window?